# Engine shuts off when gear is put in neutral

Tags: engine, vw, gasoline, hesitation, fox

I had some problems today. I was driving my VW Fox 1.4 gasoline for about 15 minutes and then, when I had to stop at the speed bump, battery and oil lights came on the dashboard, also it looked like the engine was stopped. However when I gave it more gas, engine hesitated but started to work again (This was quite similar thing as it happens during so called "turbo lag", I was pushing the gas pedal to the bottom but there was no thrust). Then the same thing repeatedly happened again for several times when I was idling or stopping, few times engine shut off completely.

When the car cooled for a hour I had to drive again and noticed the same thing about 10 minutes after starting the engine. So it looks like this happens when the engine warms up.

**EDIT** as strange as it sounds but I have noticed that this happens mostly when weather is humid or it is raining. When its not a rainy day engine works perfectly.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I would start by looking at idle air, especially the idle air motor/control (so-called IAC).  These carbon up and stop working correctly, which is most noticable after warmup and when the control goes into "closed loop".

Answer (score 1):

That combination of combustion issues could indicate dirty/worn throttle body or IAC (as mentioned by SteveRacer.)

The "turbo lag" symptom makes me think something is stuck in a way that restricts airflow.

Inspect these to diagnose, listen around the engine bay for hissing sounds that could indicate air leaking as well.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to understand what is really going on from your description.

But my guess would be something electrical.

I suggest checking:

- alternator, belt, pulleys
- crankshaft & camshaft sensors

Post more info and I will edit as well.

Comment: All belts were changed recently. Checking sensor would be a good thing I guess.